# How can I use %n to put high values into an interger?

Tags: c

If `printf("AAAA%n",  &a)` puts 4 into a, how can I put 0x403b76 into a?

Comment: print 0x403b76 characters? But why would you want to do that?

Comment: This is for a format string hack where the only way to change a is through the format string.

Comment: Just to clarify: You have the code `printf(format_string, &a)` where `a` is an integer. You can't change code but you can change `format_string`. Now you want to change `format_string` so that the integer `a` ends with the value 0x403b76. Is that it?

Comment: @4386427 this is exactly the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @deepthought I'll suggest that you edit the question and describe what you are trying to do (i.e. what you have told us in comment should be placed in the question itself)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const int size = 0x403b76;

    char *s = malloc(size+3);

    memset(s, 'a', size);

    strcpy(&s[size], "%n");

    int a;

    printf(s, &a);

    printf("\n%x\n", a);
}
```

Comment: @4386427 True. Fixed it.

Comment: Well, it does the job, I guess. Not sure OP is looking for a solution that prints 4209526 characters to stdout... but, well, a solution is a solution ;-)